# Как собрать свой jar для Java EE

Tags: java-ee, jar

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть функционал который хочу вынести в `jar` файл. Штука в том что функционал подвязан для Java EE. Как просто собрать `jar` я знаю. Но как подключить нужные файлы с Java EE к проекту. Вообще какие это файлы?

Спасибо.

Comment: javaee-api-7.0.jar

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо. помог.